# Slow query in postgreSQL osm data

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, openstreetmap

HI i have a query in PostgreSql and  speed of a query is very slow. How can I speed up query

I select a latitude and longtitude from table nodes , an use functions ST_X and ST_Y , in table nodes is 14 000 000 rows , in table way_tags 5 000 000 an in way_nodes 18 000 000 rows

How can I speed up this query or a database. I have indexes but still is it slow.

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), wt.way_id
FROM way_tags wt join way_nodes wn on (wn.way_id=wt.way_id) join nodes n on (wn.node_id=n.id)
WHERE wt.k='highway' AND wt.v='tertiary'
ORDER BY wt.way_id ASC, wn.sequence_id ASC
```

Comment: What indexes you have? try to add k+v index on way_tags table.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then edit the question accordingly.